# Problems importing Wordpress into Amazon Web Service (EC2)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I set up my server with mysql and php on Amazon with "Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03.2 (HVM)".
Then I install WordPress and now it's running perfectly on my server.

I'd like to import all the contents from my other server. So I export the posts to xml.
In my amazon server I use the import plugin of Wordpress.

However, this plugin (the import from WordPress) needs a password, and the only pass i have the .pem. So, what can I do and how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The password you need is for FTP, which is how WordPress transfers the files to your server.

If you don't have FTP set up, that's not a problem, but you'll need to install the plugin manually.

The plugin that you're after is available here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-importer/

To install, just download the zip file and upload into your `wp-content/plugins` folder.

Comment: Yes... I know... But I only access to my FTP with the .PEM password (the protect key that provides amazon) So, how can i get a "normal" password. (Do you know what I'm trying to ask?)

Comment: 2 options: amend your FTP daemon's config (not recommended, as it's less secure), or manually upload the plugin as I stated in the answer.  Manually installing the plugin is the best option here - it's quicker, easier, and more secure.

Comment: Yes! I've installed this plugin yesterday... The point is that the plugin ask me for this fields:
> FTP
> User
>Pass

And my pass is in the key (.pem)... So i don't know what to write there...

Comment: This is what i'm refering to >> http://i62.tinypic.com/246p75w.png
Because I only access the FTP via the .pem key that gave me Amazon. So What can i do?

Comment: Like I've said - you can install it manually.  Download the zip file and place it in your `wp-content/plugins` folder.  I've even provided a link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can update your wordpress themes and plugins to your amazon instance without using your .pem file. When you go to wordpress and want to update your theme or plugin and wordpress is prompting you for a [host, user, and password](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=246p75w&s=8#.VNUy0LDF-4Q) then wordpress does not have the permisions to write to your wordpress/wp-content/theme or wordpress/wp-content/plugins folders.

The best solution I have found is this answer. Add the line define('FS_METHOD','direct') in the following way:

**wp-config.php**

```
/** MySQL database name*/
define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '1234');

/** Add this line: sets up direct method for wordpress, auto-update without     
ftp **/
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

**Save and Exit**

Next you need to set permissions in the wordpress directories to give wordpress the ability to write these files when you request a new theme or plugin. More specifically, you need to apply www-data access for apache and php. For myself, I have set this permission on folders www, wordpress, wordpress/wp-content, wordpress/wp-content/plugins, and wordpress/wp-content/themes.

This is an example of the file structure I had. $HOME/www/wordpress/wp-content/...You can check your file permission with

```
ls -la
```

thru the command line first. As you set the permission you can check to make sure the www-data permission is set on the folder correctly. Here are two examples to setting the www-data permissions to allow wordpress to automatically make the update.

```
sudo chown www-data.www-data plugins  
sudo chown www-data.www-data themes
```

See this image as a further illustration of what your permissions should look like. Also note the upgrade file. That was added after I added the first theme to the wordpress app. 
[image]
[image]

The site I found a good set of basic instructions to achieving this was [here](http://rusama.net/2013/01/21/setting-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2/). I just needed to extract the details for permissions to make the automatic update work.